# How do I import an hd movie into FCPX and export it with same file size and quality of the original?

Tags: mac, final-cut-pro

So I imported an HD movie file into FCPX of one of my favorite movies. The file size was approximately 1.5 GB. I wanted to edit it to remove certain scenes, only trimming the entire 155 minute film to 150 minutes. The first time I edited it with untouched Quicktime movie settings it was just shy of 100 GB's. Then I edited using a different compressor setting to 1.46 GB and the quality and dimensions were crappy to say the least. How do I export it to the same original file size and maintain quality??? Its driving me nuts. It seems the best FCPX can do without loss of major quality (H.264 encoding) is a resulting file with the size of 16 GB's. AH!!!

Comment: Hmm. What was the format (filetype, codec) of the original movie?